# Hello, I need help fixing a bug to update the User interface

Tags: javascript

So new to javascript, been working on a little project to practice, its a timer calculator that gives the amount of hours, days, weeks and months the person been alive and the remaining time until the next birthday. I would like the user to be able to reset everything and add a new date after clicking reset then click me again. When I click the reset button it resets the timer without a problem, remove the previous days alive section but doesn't update it with the new date entered. I'm using Vs code I copied to jsfiddle to show it easier but I dont know why the button isn't working in jsfiddle, it works when I launch the index file itself.

```js
var timeout;
let counter = {
  'days': document.querySelector('.daysUnit'),
  'hours': document.querySelector('.hoursUnit'),
  'mins': document.querySelector('.minsUnit'),
  'secs': document.querySelector('.secUnit'),
  'Days': document.getElementById('Days'),
  'Weeks': document.getElementById('Weeks'),
  'Hours': document.getElementById('Hours'),
  'Months': document.getElementById('Months')

}

function ageTimer() {
  let dob = prompt("When is your birthday?", "YYYY/MM/DD");
  let dates = {
    today: new Date(),
    dobConverted: new Date(dob),
  }
  console.log(dates.today);

  function calcPassedTime() {

    let now = dates.today.getTime();
    let then = dates.dobConverted.getTime();
    let passedTime = now - then;

    let hours = Math.floor((passedTime / (1000 * 60 * 60)));
    let days = Math.floor(passedTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    let weeks = Math.floor(passedTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
    let months = Math.floor(passedTime / (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 30));

    counter.Days.innerHTML = days;
    counter.Months.innerHTML = months;
    counter.Hours.innerHTML = hours;
    counter.Weeks.innerHTML = weeks;

  }

  function countdown() {
    let dates = {
      today: new Date(),
      dobConverted: new Date(dob),
    }

    if (dates.dobConverted.getFullYear() < dates.today.getFullYear()) {
      dates.dobConverted.setFullYear(dates.today.getFullYear());
      if (dates.dobConverted.getMonth() <= dates.today.getMonth()) {
        dates.dobConverted.setFullYear(dates.today.getFullYear() + 1);
      }

    let currentTime = dates.today.getTime();
    let eventTime = dates.dobConverted.getTime();
    let diffTime = eventTime - currentTime;

    function timer(time) {
      let secUnit = Math.floor((diffTime % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
      let minsUnit = Math.floor((diffTime % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      let hoursUnit = Math.floor((diffTime % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      let daysUnit = Math.floor(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

      daysUnit = (daysUnit < 10) ? "00" + daysUnit : daysUnit;
      hoursUnit = (hoursUnit < 10) ? "0" + hoursUnit : hoursUnit;
      minsUnit = (minsUnit < 10) ? "0" + minsUnit : minsUnit;
      secUnit = (secUnit < 10) ? "0" + secUnit : secUnit;

      counter.days.innerHTML = daysUnit;
      counter.hours.innerHTML = hoursUnit;
      counter.mins.innerHTML = minsUnit;
      counter.secs.innerHTML = secUnit;
    };
    timer(diffTime);
    timeout = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
  }
  calcPassedTime();
  countdown();
}

function reset() {
  counter.Days.remove();
  counter.Months.remove();
  counter.Weeks.remove();
  counter.Hours.remove();
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  counter.days.innerHTML = "";
  counter.hours.innerHTML = "";
  counter.mins.innerHTML = "";
  counter.secs.innerHTML = "";
}
```

```css
.timer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.clock {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="head">
    <h1>The Count Down</h1>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="alive">
    <div>Age in Days: <span id="Days"></span> </div>
    <div>Age in Months: <span id="Months"></span> </div>
    <div>Age in Weeks: <span id="Weeks"></span></div>
    <div>Age in Hours: <span id="Hours"></span> </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Calculated time until next Birthday !</p>
  </div>
  <div class="timer">
    <div class="frame">Days</div>
    <div class="frame">Hours</div>
    <div class="frame">Minutes</div>
    <div class="frame">Seconds</div>
  </div>
  <div class="clock">
    <div class="daysUnit"></div>
    <div class="number">
      <div>:</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hoursUnit"></div>
    <div class="number">
      <div>:</div>
    </div>
    <div class="minsUnit"></div>
    <div class="number">
      <div>:</div>
    </div>
    <div class="secUnit"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="button">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ageTimer()">Click me</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="reset()">Reset Me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've submitted an edit to your question, pulling in the jsfiddle example, but in the future please don't post links to external resources in case they go down.

Comment: Ok, for starters, the reason the JSfiddle does not work is because it does not seem to like the fact that you call the `ageTimer()` method directly from the HTML.

Comment: Instead try adding something like this to the JS section and it will work: `document.querySelector(".btn-primary").addEventListener("click", ageTimer)
document.querySelector(".btn-danger").addEventListener("click", reset)` And you have to fix the fact that on the buttons it says `id` instead of `class`.

Comment: @AdamH thank you, I don't really know the rules for here.

Comment: @ZaideFlanders It's no problem, we all start somewhere.

Comment: any tips on solving the problem? Essentially just want the user to be able to re-enter dates without having to refresh the page.

Comment: @ZaideF I'm getting varying results depending on different time ranges when I test. I've not had a lot of time to dig further into it, but my suspicion is that the issue is somewhere in the vicinity of this if statement: `if (dates.dobConverted.getFullYear() < dates.today.getFullYear())...`. Especially the `else` at the end is not very logical in my mind. Maybe that helps you start looking...

Comment: @ced-b yeah thanls I realize now that was redondent, but the varying result I can work on tweaking out myself,  but its the button function where I need help